# React Native app really slow on adroid device

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, expo

I want to create app in react native but app in really slow on my android device. Scrolling, writing in inputs, generally whole app is laggy.

The reason is not code because boilerplate code is lagging too!

I checked app in ios device, works smooth there so the problem is on android or in my device(?). I updated expo-cli, I have remote debug option off but when I enable remote debug I've got errors:

```
Error: Unable to resolve module `./debugger-ui/ui.7beef9ab.css` from ``: 

None of these files exist:
  * debugger-ui\ui.7beef9ab.css(.native|.native.expo.ts|.expo.ts|.native.expo.tsx|.expo.tsx|.native.expo.js|.expo.js|.native.expo.jsx|.expo.jsx|.native.ts|.ts|.native.tsx|.tsx|.native.js|.js|.native.jsx|.jsx|.native.json|.json|.native.wasm|.wasm)
  * debugger-ui\ui.7beef9ab.css\index(.native|.native.expo.ts|.expo.ts|.native.expo.tsx|.expo.tsx|.native.expo.js|.expo.js|.native.expo.jsx|.expo.jsx|.native.ts|.ts|.native.tsx|.tsx|.native.js|.js|.native.jsx|.jsx|.native.json|.json|.native.wasm|.wasm)
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (D:\reactNative\wtf\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:163:15)
    at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (D:\reactNative\wtf\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ResolutionRequest.js:52:18)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (D:\reactNative\wtf\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:287:16)
    at D:\reactNative\wtf\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:267:42
    at Server.<anonymous> (D:\reactNative\wtf\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:841:41)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (D:\reactNative\wtf\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:99:24)
    at _next (D:\reactNative\wtf\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:119:9)
```

On remote debug on app working as slow as on remote debug off.
Recently I was updating react native, maybe that is the reason? I don't remember if problems started right after update tho.

package.json :

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~39.0.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.2",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-39.0.3.tar.gz",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.9.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I actually don't know what I could do more, I'm begginer in react native. I just want my app to run smooth.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Have you tried to install in release mode by following https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.html? (Release mode means by --variable=release)

Comment: I'm opening my app though expo.